# Temporal in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-temporal

I try to use Temporal in Chrome, but it fails:

```
Temporal.DateTime.from("2019-11-26T14:58:54.147Z")
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Temporal is not defined
>       at :1:1

Version: Chromium   78.0.3904.108

How to use Temporal in Chrome?

BTW. Above question is solved, but ...

> But I want more. I don't want to parse strings and convert them to an
>   object over and over again. I want to parse a JSON string and get nice
>   high level DateTime objects immediately.

Source: https://github.com/guettli/lets-fix-json/blob/master/README.md#add-datetime

Answer (score 7):

When the question was asked, [Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) was a Stage 2 proposal, so it wasn't surprising if Chrome's V8 didn't have it at that time. (It certainly wouldn't be unflagged.)

Typically JavaScript engines don't implement proposals until Stage 3 (that's part of what Stage 3 is for — more about the stages [here](https://tc39.es/process-document/)). Usually they're behind a flag initially, the eventually unflagged once they've been sufficiently field-tested, but Temporal is a special case; from the explainer linked above *(their emphasis)*:

> **NOTE: Although this proposal's API is not expected to change, implementers of this proposal MUST NOT ship unflagged Temporal implementations until IETF standardizes timezone/calendar string serialization formats. See [#1450](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal/issues/1450) for updates.**

V8 support for temporal is underway as of June 2022; [here's the tracking issue for it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=11544).

In the meantime, the proposal links to polyfills you can use [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#polyfills).

Answer (score 4):

As of today, Temporal is a [Stage 3 propsal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#status).

It is currently [not implemented in any browser](https://caniuse.com/temporal). The process of implementation is ongoing, [at least in Chrome](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5668291307634688).

There is a [polyfill available](https://github.com/js-temporal/temporal-polyfill) for experimental usage. It follows closely the existing [Temporal spec](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html).